# fancybox on IE8: invalid argument, impossible to obtain display property

Tags: jquery, fancybox

1. I am using last version of jQuery and fancybox 1.3.4.
2. This is the doctype definition: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; charset=utf-8" />`

My code uses ajax to get an array of images in database and give them to fancybox. Happens that fancybox works fine but crashes always on the last image. It outputs a blank box and the jQuery error:

> impossible to obtain display property. invalid argument. line: 1857
>   character:4

Important: I had to fix my version of jQuery because it used `getAttributeNode` and `setAttributeNode` instead of `getAttribute` and `setAttribute`.

Anyway, this is my code. I hope someone can help me!

```
$(".file_image").click( function () {

    var id_commessa = $(this).attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        cache : false,
        url : "ajax_modules/commessa/get_foto_allestimento.php?id=" + id_commessa,
        success: function(data) {
            var items = JSON.parse(data);
            if (items['error'] == 0) {
                $.fancybox(items['items'], {
                    'type' : 'image',
                    'overlayShow' : true
                });
            }
            else {
                $.boxMessage({
                    'message' : items['msg'],
                    'type' : "error"
                });         
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

this code works fine with all browsers but not wih IE8... :(

many thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `JSON.parse` is supported in IE8. jQuery however has `$.parseJSON()` which does the same thing and you can set the `dataType` option in your AJAX call to `json` and it will be parsed automatically into a JS object:

```
$.ajax({
        type     : "POST",
        cache    : false,
        dataType : 'json',
        url      : "ajax_modules/commessa/get_foto_allestimento.php?id=" + id_commessa,
        success  : function(data) {
            ...
```

If `JSON.parse` has native support in the browser then `$.parseJSON` will use it, otherwise it will use `eval`.